# Odd behavior when comparing numbers

Tags: python

I am doing a Project Euler problem, one that is fairly easy. However, I am getting a condition at the end of my loop that evaluates `0 > 5832` as `True`

I am testing the example given to verify correct implementation:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

Here is my code:

```
digits = 4
number = """
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
"""

number = number.replace("\n","")
r = 0

for x in xrange(len(number)):
    sub = number[x:x+digits]
    product = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), sub)
    if product > r:  # int(required)
        print product, ">", r
        r = product
print r
```

Digging further, I can see that the last product generated is of type string with a value of `0`, which causes the condition to evaluate True. This puzzles me - I am not sure why the last product is returned as a string rather than an int as the other products. I have it fixed by replacing the conditional with `int(product) > r`

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` will return its second argument unchanged if it has a length of one. Example:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), "234")
24
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), "34")
12
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), "4")
'4'
```

`sub` will have a length of one in the last iteration of your loop, when you're slicing past the end of the string.

You can force `reduce` to call your lambda function at least once by explicitly providing an initial argument.

```
product = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y), sub, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, I meant `product > r`. I posted the fixed version by mistake. Edited the original post to clarify. Thank you for your reply, that works well, and better clarifies `reduce` (which is not something I work with often, so I'm a bit unfamiliar with it). 

I also could have avoided the problem with `xrange(len(number)-(digits-1))` in the loop to avoid iterating to the very end.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Kevin's answer as he correctly identified the reason I was having trouble, namely that I was misusing `reduce`.

I could have also made a list of the subset like so:

```
for x in xrange(len(number)):
    sub = [int(n) for n in number[x:x+digits]]
    product = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, sub)
    if product > r:
        r = product
```